# iOS, what should I set architectures setting in my project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

After doing some minor modifications to my app and loading it up into the latest xcode version, I've noticed the following settings.

Should I remove armv6?
The option in the drop down says armv7, armv7s.

What should I set ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't really want to support iPhone `3G` and lower (not `3GS`) then you can remove `armv6`. If you do, then you'll need to support only `iOS 4.*` and lower, and i don't think you really need it.

So, you can feel free to remove `armv6` from the list.

Answer (score 1):

As shown is image, If you select both architectures, the product built will execute on all iOS devices including iPhone 3G. If you have to run your code on iPhone 3GS or above. You can set armv7 in setting.

Comment: in fact armv7 includes iPhone 3GS too

Comment: @jMelnik so I can remove armv6 in either case and still run on 3G and all other iPhones ?

Comment: @Jules as i wrote in my answer, armv6 is needed for 3G and lower. So, if you remove it, you won't be able to run your app on those devices, but 3GS and higher will be supported with armv7, iphone 5 has armv7s.

Comment: @dreamzor so I can leave as is and apple will accept it ? I thought you had to removed armv6

Comment: if you remove armv6 your app will not run on iPhone(original) and iPhone 3G. But it will still run on iPhone 3GS, 4 and 4S. For the iPhone 5 you'll have to add the armv7s.

Comment: @Jules you better choose armv7 and armv7s (which is standard) if you don't care about 3G and lower. I don't think you do care.

Comment: @dreamzor I'm getting an error now, any ideas ? ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: SNIP DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @Jules you need to update your third-party libraries to the latest versions, so they should support armv7s.

Answer (score 1):

- Set ARMv6 if you want to support iPhone(original) and iPhone 3G.
- Set ARMv7 if you want to support iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S
- Set ARMv7s if you want to support iPhone 5

[Here](http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/07/19/ought-arm/) is a little explanation about the basics on iPhone processors technology.

Just for the record, iPhone(original), 3G and 3GS were discontinued.

Comment: I wouldn't set ARMv7s to support iPhone 5 until I had an iPhone 5 to test on. As far as I can tell, the 5 can run ARMv7 code just fine, and I trust that farther than I trust compiled code that I can't even run…